# How to use Cloud Storage library to work with files that have been uploaded with with BlobstoreService on the development server?

Tags: google-app-engine

On the local development server, I upload a file to a GCS bucket (using withGoogleStorageBucketName when creating the upload URL) and in the callback FileInfo.getGsObjectName() returns a name starting with "fake-encoded_gs_key:". I can use that name to serve the file with BlobstoreService just fine, but when I try to use the Cloud Storage client library to work with this name (and the same bucket I uploaded to), for example to copy it, I get:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService@6117755b: No such file: GcsFilename(app_default_bucket, fake-encoded_gs_key:YXB...281)
```

Under /target/appname/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/ a file with a name starting with "encoded_gs_key:" is created, and the long part after that differs from the long part after "fake-encoded_gs_key:" mentioned earlier.

How can I make this work on the development server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be running into the following bug:
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9000

> Dev server fails to serve Google Storage file

Do you have to use both Cloud Storage Library and Blobstore API? If not, why not just use Cloud Storage library without BlobstoreService. Try the following example that uses just the client library by default:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client/blob/master/java/example/src/com/google/appengine/demos/GcsExampleServlet.java

```
// Create object via client library.
GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService();
GcsFilename filename = new GcsFilename(BUCKETNAME, FILENAME);
gcsService.createOrReplace(filename, GcsFileOptions.getDefaultInstance());
....
// Read object via client library.
GcsInputChannel readChannel = gcsService.openReadChannel(filename, 0);
```

Comment: Hello and welcome.  Please consider adding more detail to this answer.  Particularly make sure that the important information from the links is contained or quoted in this post.

Comment: Thanks, JasonMArcher. I've added some relevant quotes here now.

Comment: Thanks, I starred the issue and will be waiting for Google's resolution.

I do need to use both APIs - I use Blobstore for the efficient upload and thumbnail generation and Cloud Storage for copying and getting the content on the server side.

My workaround is checking if I'm in development environment and if so, get the bytes from the blob and create a CS object with the same byte content.